# Use numpy array as lambda argument?

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, functional-programming

Is there a reasonable way to get the following done on one line? I'd really like to avoid creating a temporary variable or a separate function.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
x = np.ma.masked_where(x>2, x)
```

I tried

```
x = map(lambda x: np.ma.masked_where(x>2, x), np.array([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

but the map object is not what I want? I can of course define separate fuction, which avoids assigning variable:

```
masker = lambda x: np.ma.masked_where(x>2, x)
x = masker(np.array([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Comment: In your second "attempt", you would still be creating the intermediate array, you just aren't assigning it.  I'm confused why the first approach isn't what you want

Comment: Why this need for a one-liner?

Comment: I understand I cannot avoid creating an intermediate array, just want to avoid assigning it. Why, just trying to look for ways to be more functional with numpy.

Comment: The assignment of the intermediate array causes absolutely no problems, because you immediately reassign the same variable with the final result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `map` at all, just an anonymous function. All you will do is replace the initial assignment to `x` with a parameter binding in a function call.

```
import numpy as np
# x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
# x = np.ma.masked_where(x>2, x)

x = (lambda x: np.ma.masked_where(x>2, x))(np.array([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's what I was looking for, but couldn't figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This works great for me and is one liner:

```
>>> x = (lambda y: np.ma.masked_where(y>2, y))(np.array([1,2,3,4,5]))
>>> print (x)
[1 2 -- -- --]
>>>
```

Comment: How is this different from chepner's answer? :)

Comment: It is not. I didn't refresh the page while testing on my computer and posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this with `map`:

```py
import numpy as np

x = map(
    np.ma.masked_where, 
    *(np.array([1,2,3,4,5])>2, np.array([1,2,3,4,5]))
)
```

Map returns an iterable, so to review the masking, go like:

```py
>>> for item in x:
...     print(item)
... 
1
2
--
--
--
```

Comment: Interesting, but I guess iteration over individual elements is not what one usually does with numpy arrays.